# npm won't start

Tags: angular

My npm won't start, following is the error I got

> D:\angular\AngularTemplate (2)\AngularTemplate\AngularTemplate\Angular-GettingStarted-master\APM-Start>npm start
>       module.js:540
>           throw err;
>           ^

Comment: Is this from my course? Did you do an `npm install` before the `npm start`?

Comment: yes i have already installed npm

Comment: @DeborahK meant "did you install node modules for your project". It is not about installing npm but running command "npm install" for your project (where `package.json` is located). What this will do is to install all of the dependencies defined in `package.json` for your project and put them in a folder called `node_modules`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You have to:

1) Install npm and ensure you have a relatively recent version. npm is "node package manager". It includes tools to help you download the packages you need to run most modern web applications.

2) Navigate to the appropriate folder (which it looks like you have done).

3) Use `npm install` to install all of the packages that Angular requires using the npm you installed in step 1. This reads the package.json file found in the APM-Start folder to determine the list of packages to install.

NOTE: This is NOT the same as installing npm. Here we are *USING* the npm we installed in step 1 to install the packages for our Angular application.

4) Use `npm start` to run the application.

Comment: but i have installed npm 3 times but still it's giving same error

Comment: I just clarified my answer. Installing npm is *not* the same as *using* npm to install the packages needed for the application. Please follow the steps above.

Comment: Please re-watch the "First Things First" module, starting with "Setting up our environment". I walk you through this process step by step.